# Nested auto wiring with generics in Spring

Tags: java, spring, generics, dependency-injection

My understanding is that from spring 4 and onward, a generic type can serve as a valid qualifier. This works just fine in the following (basic) example:

```
public interface TypeResolver<T>{
   Class<T> type();
}
```

```
@Configuration
public TypeResolversConfig{

   @Bean
   public TypeResolver<Integer> integerTypeResolver(){
      return () -> Integer.class
   }

   @Bean
   public TypeResolver<String> stringTypeResolver(){
      return () -> String.class
   }
}
```

```
@Service
public class SomeService{

   @Autowired
   private TypeResolver<Integer> integerTypeResolver;
}
```

However if I add another bean as such:

```
@Service
public class SomeOtherService<T>{

   @Autowired
   private TypeResolver<T> tTypeResolver;

}
```

And then proceed to edit `SomeService` as follows:

```
@Service
public class SomeService{

   @Autowired
   private SomeOtherService<Integer> someOtherService;
}
```

I get a

> Field tTypeResolver in com.example.demo.SomeOtherService required a single bean, but 2 were found

exception. Is there any way around this, or is this just an inherent limitation whereby spring can only get around type erasure to a limited extent? I am using spring boot 2.1.8.RELEASE.

Answer (score 0):

Generics are not present during compile time,so Autowiring generic type  is meaning less.
So you can achieve this one by like this

```
@Service
public class SomeService{

   @Autowired
   private TypeResolver<Integer> integerTypeResolver;

   @Autowired
   private TypeResolver<String> stringTypeResolver;

   ...
}
```

NO need of `SomeOtherService`.

Comment: sorry for previous ans.You are right.So I edited my answer.Please check my edited answer

Comment: Back to the original error I'm afraid. Adding `@Scope("singleton")` to the bean definitions did not solve the problem.

Comment: "Generics are not present during compile time" generics most certainly are present at compile time.